# Propositional Calculus: Stating and verifying readability and unique readability of a given language $\mathcal{L^*}$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

**Problem:** Consider the set of symbols * and #. Let $\mathcal{L^*}$ be the smallest set $L$ of sequences of these symbols with the following properties:
a) The length one sequences $\langle\mbox{*}\rangle$ and $\langle$#$\rangle$ belong to $L$
b) If $\sigma$ and $\tau$ belong to $L$, then so do $\langle\mbox{*}\rangle+\sigma+\langle\mbox{#}\rangle$ and $\langle\mbox{*}\rangle+\sigma+\tau+\langle\mbox{#}\rangle$.

State Readability and Unique Readability for $\mathcal{L^*}$ and determine for each whether it holds.

How do we determine what makes it readable? How do we construct these criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unique Readability for $\mathcal{L^*}$:** Suppose $\phi \in \mathcal{L^*}$. Then exactly one of the following conditions applies :

(1) $\phi =\langle \mbox{*} \rangle$
(2) $\phi = \langle \mbox{#} \rangle$
(3) There is a $\psi \in \mathcal{L^*}$ such that $\phi = \langle \mbox{*} \rangle + \psi + \langle \mbox{#} \rangle $.
(4) There are $\psi_1, \psi_2 \in \mathcal{L^*}$ such that $\phi = \langle \mbox{*} \rangle + \psi_1 + \psi_2 + \langle \mbox{#} \rangle $.

Further, $\psi$ in (3) and $\psi_1, \psi_2$ in (4) are unique.

A quick check shows that the subset $L$ of $\mathcal{L^*}$ satisfying the above clauses is $\mathcal{L^*}$ itself. We want to show that readability holds, meaning that the cases are mutually exclusive.

**Readable?:** Say $\phi = \langle \mbox{*} \rangle$ Then it obviously cannot be (2), and vice versa. It cannot be (3) since (3) must be a sequence of at least three (since the empty set is not a "formula"). It cannot be (4) either since (4) must be a sequence of length at least four. The last two results can also be said for  $\phi = \langle \mbox{#} \rangle$. All that remains is to show that (3) and (4) are mutually exclusive. Suppose $\phi = \langle \mbox{*} \rangle + \psi + \langle \mbox{#} \rangle = \langle \mbox{*} \rangle + \psi_1 + \psi_2 + \langle \mbox{#} \rangle $.  
$\implies \psi = \psi_1 + \psi_2$. Can we make this happen? (Can the concatenation of two formulas be a formula?)

Take $\psi_1 = \mbox{*} \tau \mbox{#} $ and $\psi_2= \mbox{*} \sigma \mbox{#}$. Call $\psi =\psi_1 +\psi_2 = \mbox{*} \tau \mbox{#}\mbox{*} \sigma \mbox{#}$ is an element if $\tau \mbox{#}\mbox{*} \sigma$ is. Suppose $\tau = \mbox{*}, \sigma = \mbox{#}$. Then we have $\mbox{*} \mbox{#} \mbox{*}\mbox{#}$ is an element by (4), so $\mbox{*} \mbox{*} \mbox{#}\mbox{*} \mbox{#} \mbox{#}$ is of form (3) and (4) and thus they are not mutually exclusive $\therefore$ $\mathcal{L^*}$ is not readable.

**Uniquely Readable?**: Unnecessary since the language is not readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the statement for unique readability written out right, but the problem is that the language is not uniquely readable.

To see this, we can construct
a=<*>+<*>+<#>,
b=<*>+<#>+<#>,
c=<*>+<*>+<#>+<*>+<#>+<#>

Now, since a, b, and c are all in L*, <*>+a+b+<#> and <*>+c+<#> are also each in L*.
But <*>+a+b+<#> = <*>+c+<#>, so a+b=c, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your empty brackets, I'm assuming you mean *?

Comment: Do you agree that the language is at least readable by my proof?

Comment: Well I think readable has to mean that a formula has to be in the form of exactly one condition from your (1) through (4). And it fails to be fit the 'exactly' part of the definition. But if readability only means that that a formula needs to be in at least one of the forms from (1) through (4), then I see no reason why readability should fail.

Comment: Yea I meant to write *, it doesn't show up because I didn't use appropriate formatting.

Comment: Maybe if you combined conditions (3) and (4) everything would work out. The sequences I constructed are identical, after all. The only problem with them was that they could be derived in more than one way.

Comment: fixed the "proof"